# How to disable the Check box from the multipleSelect?

Tags: jquery, multiple-select

[image]                                         I have the searchable drop down in my modal.  I want the user to be able to select only one option and I have done that as well. But the problem is I want to disable the checkbox and if user clicks on the text the option should be selected.

My code:

```
 $('#dend').multipleSelect({
            isopen: true,
            multipleWidth: 55,
            filter: true,
            selectAll: false,
            single: true
        });
```

Comment: you can use the select2 plugin

Comment: the problem is i was not allowed to use any plugins

Comment: i can not help without the code

Comment: @DeveViru don't you think that is already done?

Comment: Provide complete html code. Are you using bootstrap select 2? not clear from little bit code

Comment: Did you using plugin http://multiple-select.wenzhixin.net.cn/getting-started/ ? You can refer examples given on that website too. http://multiple-select.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/

Comment: you mean you want click the text to select one option not checbox ? so you don't need  use multipleSelect and checkbox ,why not use normal select ?  when you disabled the radio, Conventionally, it is to disable the entire option；

Comment: thanks for your comment guys..the problem is i am not allowed to use any other plugins..i am using the following plugin   http://multiple-select.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/